# Has a life raft ever been successfully deployed in case of an accident?

Tags: accidents

Has a life rift ever been successfully deployed in the event of an air accident?

By successfully I mean removed from the aircraft, placed on the water, inflated and used by passengers/crew as a life raft.

Comment: This question is too broad. The answer is yes, many, many, many times. You need to narrow it down in scope to get a reasonable answer.

Comment: It's really not all that broad and [it is singularly answerable](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/65612/5517). Might not be the answer the OP is after, but it's a simple, concrete answer to the question.

Comment: Actually I should have limited it to commercial airliners. Pants.

Comment: It's typically not well-received when [an edit invalidates an answer](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3103/14897). Please consider reverting back to the original question, and ask a new one with more details if you want. Before you do, a Cessna 152 can be flown commercially, so be sure to *properly limit the scope,* to say, jet-liners than are heavier than x kg, flying over oceans and not rivers, etc. Whatever you have in mind, but in detail.

Comment: Voted to close, I'll try again, but it's frustrating that there is no way to fix it and keep the existing answers that are appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Sure.  For example, Eddie Rickenbacker and 6 other people spent 3 weeks adrift aboard life rafts after their B-17 ditched in WW2.

Read more -- https://www.historynet.com/eddie-rickenbacker-and-six-other-people-survive-a-b-17-crash-and-three-weeks-lost-in-the-pacific-ocean.htm

Comment: I'm not sure if a WW2 bomber qualify as commercial

Comment: @QuentinH that qualification was edited in after this answer. Hate it when an edit invalidates an answer.

Comment: @Jamiec nicely spotted, I should have checked. Maybe the other guys did order some US "carpets" with next-day delivery though... that would make the answer valid.

Comment: Btw the linked article could be used as the basis for other questions.  Specifically-- . "In the end, however, all Y could provide was a compass course reading, which was worthless since that did not tell the crew whether they were flying toward or away from their destination. Without a bearing the pilot did not know in which direction to fly."  -- How is this plausible?  The author would have us believe "island Y" could tell the B-17 which direction it was flying but could not provide a bearing?  This makes no sense.  Actually, it's so nonsensical that it's probably not a good subject for a q

Comment: "An hour before the estimated arrival time, Captain Cherry throttled back, slowly descended to about 1,000 feet and began looking for Canton Island."  -- this makes no sense either, unless there was an overcast above this level -- you've been flying over  the ocean for almost 2000 miles and you don't know exactly where you are so your strategy is to descend  to a thousand feet, where your field of view will be greatly limited-- a whole hour before your ETA?  Interesting.  I don't think the author was a pilot.

Comment: It would be interesting to find a more authoritative/ plausible description of the flight.

Answer (score 2):

[US Airways Flight 1549](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/US_Airways_Flight_1549) ditched in the Hudson river after a multi-engine bird strike on January 15, 2009.
According to these pictures, they did deploy the emergency slides which were eventually detached and used as emergency rafts:

[image]
[image]
[image]

---

Emergency slides in airliners are actual life rafts. They are designed for that and often include survival kits and canopies:

[image]

Comment: I agree with @ymb, the criteria (from the start) was that the life rafts be deployed. Make-shift rafts make out of slides don't count I'm afraid.

Comment: Slides are NOT make-shift rafts. They are designed to be rafts once everyone is out of the aircraft.

Comment: Some even have sun canopies https://i.pinimg.com/originals/ad/08/40/ad0840f0f4e3ad8640d0e7b38227ff8f.jpg